# Send a html string in multipart post call using rest client ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am using RestClient ruby gem to make a multipart call like below and it works fine

```
RestClient.post 'my_url', {:myfile => File.new("/path/to/image.jpg", 'rb') ,:multipart => true}
```

In second case I have a html string like this `"<html> <title>sometitle</title></html>"`

I want to post this html as a file in above call. Is it possible to post the above html in the call below.

One option is to create a new file with above html content and use that but I don't want to do this. I am new to ruby . Can anyone help.

Comment: As I see things, you'll only have to URL encode the string and then send it.

Comment: Ok I tried this    RestClient.post 'my_url', {:myfile => "<html> <title>sometitle</title></html>".encode ,:multipart => true} but it is not working . Any suggestions.

Comment: "Not working" is too broad. What does it says? What is the error?

Comment: Besides, this way is is not escaped. This string has  special chars and it it is going to be sent via a web protocol, it needs to be URL encoded. I don't know if RestClient does this, but since it is not working...